# How to add the cursor of the position on the iOS Google Map app?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, cordova

I'm using Cordova.

On a screen, I expect user to click on a link triggering:
`window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?ll=' + myLon + ',' + myLat, '_system', 'location=no');`

On iPhone, this opens the `Plans` app, what I want.

However, how to add the cursor on the map showing the position?

Comment: A cursor is placed using this url: `window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?q=' + myPlace, '_system', 'location=no');` but why not with geo points?

Comment: It's how apple maps works, you can't control it